# Play Slick(2.6.x) with H2: table not found

Tags: playframework, h2, slick

> To reproduce the error, please find [play-slick-todos](https://github.com/YikSanChan/play-slick-todos).

I follow the pattern in [play-slick-sample](https://github.com/playframework/play-slick/tree/master/samples/basic) to implement a todo list API endpoint using Playframework and Slick. To simplify the problem, I implement only the `index` endpoint.

After `sbt run` is done, visit `localhost:9000` hits the `index` endpoint in `Application`. However, it throws below errors:

```
[error] application -

! @797hp92i6 - Internal server error, for (GET) [/] ->

play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$$anon$1: Execution exception[[JdbcSQLException: Table "todo" not found; SQL statement:
select "id", "content" from "todo" [42102-197]]]
    at play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$.throwableToUsefulException(HttpErrorHandler.scala:251)
    at play.api.http.DefaultHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:178)
    at play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(AkkaHttpServer.scala:363)
    at play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(AkkaHttpServer.scala:361)
    at scala.concurrent.Future.$anonfun$recoverWith$1(Future.scala:413)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.$anonfun$transformWith$1(Promise.scala:37)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:60)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$AbstractBatch.processBatch(BatchingExecutor.scala:55)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch.$anonfun$run$1(BatchingExecutor.scala:91)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:12)
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "todo" not found; SQL statement:
select "id", "content" from "todo" [42102-197]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:357)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:155)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableOrView(Parser.java:5920)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableFilter(Parser.java:1430)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSimpleFromPart(Parser.java:2138)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSimple(Parser.java:2287)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSub(Parser.java:2133)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectUnion(Parser.java:1946)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelect(Parser.java:1919)
```

Seems that Slick doesn't create the "todo" table for me.

I know how to create a table: For [todos](https://github.com/YikSanChan/play-slick-todos/blob/master/app/dao/TodoDAO.scala#L15), `Await.result(db.run(todos.schema.create))` does the job. But I don't know where to put them, and I believe this should have done by Slick and Play.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

```
versions:
play - 2.6.18
scala - 2.12.6
h2 - 1.4.197
play-slick - 3.0.1
play-slick-evolutions - 3.0.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The diff](https://github.com/YikSanChan/play-slick-todos/commit/d1b5c8e313c550875723afc6052f6c5bec4c246e) answers the question. I should add an evolution script.